# Mysql query with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, drop-down-menu

I need to make a query with multiple conditions it show results from an internal search engine, it should look for certain words in certain columns, but these "words" are divided by three categories WOOD, PLASTIC, ALL MATERIALS.

So in my search textbox a have a dropdown menu with the categories what i did is that:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE mat1 OR mat2 OR mat3  LIKE '%$string%' ") or die(mysq_error);
```

this working fine WITHOUT THE DROPDOWN value but i need another parameter in the query which is the categories from the dropdown menu, i tried:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE mat1 OR mat2 OR mat2 AND sex = '%$kind%' LIKE '%$string%' ") or die(mysq_error);
```

$kind contain the value of the dropdow box, wood, plastic, all materials. 
any help?
thank you

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say that the materials are not divided in separate columns but they are mixxed inside a single column called SEX

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use `REGEXP` in MySQL if your search is like `%<text>%`

Comment: have you even spent 5 minutes learning SQL ?!

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE (mat1 LIKE '%$string%' OR mat2 LIKE '%$string%' OR mat3 LIKE '%$string%') AND sex = '$kind'") or die(mysq_error);
```